# What distant observer would see if spaceship remains insitu just outside event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, frame-dragging

Imagine 2 spaceships found themselves just outside the event horizon of a blackhole, spaceship A tries to remain in place relative to the black hole while B accelerates around the blackhole. To a distant observer would see both circling around or just one being still? I read somewhere that blackhole can drag the spacetime around so which scenario is seen by the outside observer?

Comment: @BowlOfRed: oh I saw my mistake and edited.

Comment: By "accelerate", what do you mean? Is the black hole spinning or non-spinning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the hole is rotating or not. A spaceship accelerating radially outward will still be dragged along the direction of rotation, in the case of a spinning hole. A faraway observer will see one ship go around the hole, because of its transverse velocity (like a satellite orbiting the Earth), and the other spaceship, initially stationary, will aquire a transverse velocity. It depends on the rotation velocity of the hole how the velocities of the ships develop. If the first ships orbits against the rotation of the hole, it will stop orbiting and reverse direction. But ultimately, both will end up orbiting the black hole with equal angular velocities (if they orbit at equal heights.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, the light to observe the spaceships will be too red-shifted, so the black hole would be observed as black (no spaceship seen).
However, if the black hole were non rotating then it would be impossible to accelerate around, since to remain at the horizon you need to go at the speed of light in the direction opposite to the centre. moving in other direction means you don't move away at the speed of light meaning you fall inward. From your final sentence I think you mean a rotating black hole, in which case Felicia's answer applies